# Genymotion nothing happends when starting a device

Tags: android, genymotion

The line just flashes for a second and then nothing.

> This is what the genymotion.log shows:

```
2019-12-09T09:32:15+02:00 [Genymotion:461] [debug] [VBox] Call: ("showvminfo", "-- machinereadable", "e6d02ed7-f5ba-4697-bcbb-231b57e25e32")
2019-12-09T09:32:15+02:00 [Genymotion:461] [debug] [VBox] Return code: 0
2019-12-09T09:32:15+02:00 [Genymotion:461] [debug] [VBox] Call: ("showvminfo", "--machinereadable", "e6d02ed7-f5ba-4697-bcbb-231b57e25e32")
2019-12-09T09:32:15+02:00 [Genymotion:461] [debug] [VBox] Return code: 0
2019-12-09T09:32:15+02:00 [Genymotion:461] [warning] Cannot start device "Custom Phone" , status is 4
```

> This is what is what the log prints when I try to edit the device settings:

```
2019-12-09T09:39:18+02:00 [Genymotion:461] [warning] qrc:///Genymotion/Popup/StyledPopup.qml:162:9: QML QQuickItem: Binding loop detected for property "implicitWidth"
2019-12-09T09:39:18+02:00 [Genymotion:461] [warning] qrc:///Genymotion/Popup/StyledPopup.qml:162:9: QML QQuickItem: Binding loop detected for property "implicitWidth"
2019-12-09T09:39:18+02:00 [Genymotion:461] [warning] qrc:///Genymotion/Popup/StyledPopup.qml:162:9: QML QQuickItem: Binding loop detected for property "implicitWidth"
2019-12-09T09:39:24+02:00 [Genymotion:461] [debug] Edit device "e6d02ed7-f5ba-4697-bcbb-231b57e25e32"
2019-12-09T09:39:24+02:00 [Genymotion:461] [debug] onDeviceWorkerChanged "e6d02ed7-f5ba-4697-bcbb-231b57e25e32" 0
2019-12-09T09:39:24+02:00 [Genymotion:461] [debug] [findClosestTemplate] uuid "df785e5b-b1bf-470b-af5d-0c28a3d98a26" platform "p" androidVersion "9.0.0"
2019-12-09T09:39:24+02:00 [Genymotion:461] [debug] [findClosestTemplate] uuid "df785e5b-b1bf-470b-af5d-0c28a3d98a26" platform "p" androidVersion "9.0.0"
2019-12-09T09:39:24+02:00 [Genymotion:461] [debug] [VBox] Call: ("showvminfo", "--machinereadable", "e6d02ed7-f5ba-4697-bcbb-231b57e25e32")
2019-12-09T09:39:25+02:00 [Genymotion:461] [debug] [VBox] Return code: 0
2019-12-09T09:39:25+02:00 [Genymotion:461] [debug] Device status "Process"
2019-12-09T09:39:25+02:00 [Genymotion:461] [debug] Device was not fully stopped, stopping it now
2019-12-09T09:39:25+02:00 [Genymotion:461] [debug] [VBox] Call: ("controlvm", "Custom Phone", "poweroff")
2019-12-09T09:39:25+02:00 [Genymotion:461] [critical] [VBox] Return code: 1
2019-12-09T09:39:25+02:00 [Genymotion:461] [critical] [VBox] Output command: "VBoxManage: error: Machine 'Custom Phone' is not currently running"
2019-12-09T09:39:25+02:00 [Genymotion:461] [warning] Device is still running
2019-12-09T09:39:25+02:00 [Genymotion:461] [warning] QObject::connect: Cannot queue arguments of type 'Status'
(Make sure 'Status' is registered using qRegisterMetaType().)
2019-12-09T09:39:25+02:00 [Genymotion:461] [debug] onDeviceWorkerChanged "e6d02ed7-f5ba-4697-bcbb-231b57e25e32" 0
2019-12-09T09:39:25+02:00 [Genymotion:461] [debug] [findClosestTemplate] uuid "df785e5b-b1bf-470b-af5d-0c28a3d98a26" platform "p" androidVersion "9.0.0"
2019-12-09T09:39:25+02:00 [Genymotion:461] [debug] [findClosestTemplate] uuid "df785e5b-b1bf-470b-af5d-0c28a3d98a26" platform "p" androidVersion "9.0.0"
```

Comment: Did you try to run another virtual device? Or have you recently updated ?

Comment: @NightFury Haven't tried another virtual device / didn't update

Comment: Try another device, and make sure your system specs meet the requirements of Genymotion. Sometimes, graphic driver causes the issue as well. Moreover, I hope virtualization is already enabled

Comment: Thanks man it's working on the second device, I probably messed up the previous one since I can't even delete it

Comment: Glad to hear you were able to move forward. Cheers!